# After publishing an azure app service, I don't get the same result as local. Only displays "Array"

Tags: php, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I am setting up an Azure App service with an azure sql database. If I run the website on my local machine, everything works fine. After publishing, the website, after I pressed for example register or login, is displaying "Array".

In the firewall of the sql database I turned "Allow access to Azure services" on.

Connection to db:

```php
$connectionInfo = array("UID" => "viergewinnt@viergewinnt", "pwd" => "{password}", "Database" => "{database}", "LoginTimeout" => 30, "Encrypt" => 1, "TrustServerCertificate" => 0);
    $serverName = "{servername}";
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

I copied the connection from the azure example.

Snippet of Login:

```php
session_start();

    require('database.php');

    // User already logged in
    if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] == true) {
        header('Location: index.html');
        exit();
    }
    else {

        // If input is not given, show the form
        if (!empty($_POST["login"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])) {
            $login = htmlspecialchars($_POST["login"]);
            $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST["password"]);
        }
...
```

If successfuly logged in:

```php
if ($result = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC )) {
                if (password_verify($password, $result['password'])) {
                    // Check if user is confirmed
                    if ($result['confirmed'] == 1) {
                        echo "angemeldet";
                        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
                        header('Location: index.html');
                        exit();
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "User not yet confirmed.";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    echo "Password is wrong.";
                }
            }
```

After I clicked on login the site gets white and on the top left stands "Array". I don't know why because nowhere I echo Array.

I suspect that the web app doesn't has full access to the database.

Comment: var_dump() it instead of echoing. There's clearly an echo somewhere in your script, stick a die() in and random places until you find it (or better yet, use XDebug)

Comment: You shouldn't use `htmlspecialchars` where you are. That should only be used for outputting to a browser, and a password should never be being outputted.

Comment: are you sure the remote files are identical?

Comment: @delboy1978uk I looked through all echos. I only echo simple Strings. Also the thing is that on my local machine it works fine. So I suspect the problem is somewhere when I publish it.

Comment: how do you deploy your files?

Comment: @delboy1978uk I connected it with github and it's up to date. The branch is correct also.

Comment: so the live webserver (not local) does a git pull to get the latest files?

Comment: you can use a git repo to get the code for the website. You can update it, but it's not pulling everytime when someone visites the site.

Comment: ok you need to make sure you have pulled the latest code onto your server then

Comment: sounds like someone was live debugging on production, or just forgot to take his degbug code out